# Switch focus between editor and terminal in rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I want to know how to toggle the script editor and the console in RStudio (windows). I know that if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> I'll switch from editor to console, but pressing again don't change from console to script.

Comment: Check the keyboard shortcuts on the support page https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-the-RStudio-IDE

Comment: Cursor to script: Ctrl+1, cursor to console: Ctrl+2

Comment: Thankiuu ctrl1 and ctrl2 works!